# What is the reason for styling outer ul position relative and inner ul position absolute in navigation menu?

Tags: css

I have been working on navigation menus for almost 10 days. Here is the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etBlGtM4d_w&t=3s) from which I implemented navigation menu. It is working fine. But I couldn't understand the code properly, spacially "position property

**"What is the reason for assigning `position:relative` to the "outer ul" and assigning `position:absolute` to the "two inner uls(unorder lists)"?**

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#menu ul li {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

#menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

#menu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

#menu ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

#menu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 120px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">two</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">two.one</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">two.two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">two.three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">two.four</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">two.five</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">four</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">five</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: The easiest way to gain an intuitive understanding is to remove `position: relative` from the parent and see what happens. Then remove `position: absolute` from the child and, again, see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Start by understanding the concepts: [CSS Position documentation](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) especially look at the absolute: "It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor," and relative: "The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document"

So the your outer element (a `ul` in this case) is positioned relative to it's ancestor (the `<div id="menu">`) then the child is positioned absolute from that ancestor. The same thing where a `ul` is inside a `ul` - it targets the inner `ul` when you have `#menu ul ul`  in the CSS.

Here is a general breakdown:

```css
/* remove all the padding and margins that the browser sets by default */
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
/* remove the normal display for a ul as a bullet */
#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
/* style and position the inner li relative to the parent ul */
#menu ul li {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
/* make a link 'a' element show as a block and style it a bit */
#menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

#menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
/* position the inner ul absolute to the outer ul (but hide it with the 'display: none' */
#menu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
/* when we hover over a li, show the child ul */
#menu ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}
/* position the innermost ul from its acestor at the top with a 120px margin */
#menu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 120px;
  top: 0px;
}
```